# How can I remove Ubuntu from my computer?

Tags: uninstall

I installed it but all my files have been lost. I had Windows 7 before that.

How do I remove Ubuntu from my computer? How do I recover my files?

Comment: After you had chosen to replace Windows by Ubuntu you had overwritten your Windows installation and your data. You may be able to recover parts of your data but likely not your Windows installation. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu.

Comment: I guess you've formatted your entire HDD before installing Ubuntu. And consider to ask one question at the time, remove Ubuntu or to recover your files...

Comment: @GediminasJeremiahGudelis This really is one question, in that it would bad bad to try to remove Ubuntu *before* recovering the files. It's very good they were asked together in this case, because really they're both about the same problem, and generic advice about how to remove Ubuntu would be harmful if followed in this situation.

Comment: @Dineshkumar No, following any such technique would destroy most (if not all) of what's left of any recoverable data. The only way to remove Ubuntu *and* recover files is to attempt file recovery *first*. So this question is really primarily about file recovery, not primarily about removing Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you please run in Ubuntu terminal `sudo fdisk -l` it will ask for your password, edit your question and add the result. We will have an idea of what happened to your files if you do so.

Answer (score 2):

Have you overwritten your Win7 volume with Ubuntu installation?

Please don't try removing Ubuntu first, instead, recover your data before writing anything to your hard disk, as early as you can. Try boot WinPE from your USB disk, and run data recovery tools like Easy Recovery, FinalData, Recuva, etc. (Please be patient while your data are recovered, while running any of those tools or others.)

After that you just need to reinstall Win7 on that partition. If you can't boot from your new Win7 on you hard disk, you should repair your MBR, perhaps [this blog](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/) can help you.

Best luck with you!